# How do you use a gazebo world in rviz moveit?

Tags: gazebo, rviz, moveit, ros-kinetic

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I tried using my robot urdf and world sdf file in rviz moveit, but only the robot urdf showed up. The objects in my worldf file did not. Is there any easy way to use an established world file in moveit?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/285039/how-do-you-use-a-gazebo-world-in-rviz-moveit?/) by [stan25](https://answers.ros.org/users/34092/stan25/) on ROS Answers with karma: 11 on 2018-03-10

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2018-03-11**:
Cross-post of [moveit-users/Gazebo World File to Rviz Moveit](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/moveit-users/d9lCpYiZRuM).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

See https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/moveit-users/C5r9Liqh6rU

---

Originally posted by [Dave Coleman](https://answers.ros.org/users/1279/dave-coleman/) with karma: 1396 on 2018-03-13

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1